# BeautifulSoup scraping .text attribute problem

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to scrape a page, https://www.hotukdeals.com

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.hotukdeals.com/hot"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
deals = soup.find_all("article")
for deal in deals:
    priceElement = deal.find("span",{"class":"thread-price"})
    try:
        print(priceElement,priceElement.text)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

For some reason, this works, scraping the prices of deals, for a certain number of times in the loop, and then stops working.

Program output:

```
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£9.09</span> £9.09
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£39.95</span> £39.95
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£424.98</span> £424.98
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£8.10</span> £8.10
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£14.59</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£2.50</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl text--color-greyShade">£20</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£19</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£29</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl text--color-greyShade">£49.97</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">FREE</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£2.49</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£1.99</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£54.99</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£12.85</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£1.99</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£21.03</span>
<span class="thread-price text--b cept-tp size--all-l size--fromW3-xl">£5.29</span>
```

As you can see from the output, after the first four lines, the `.text` attribute is empty, but there is text in the element.

Anybody know anything about this? Any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautifulsoup needs `html5lib` parser to parse the site correctly, e.g.:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.hotukdeals.com/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html5lib")  # <-- use html5lib

for price in soup.select(".thread-price"):
    print(price.text)
```

Prints:

```
£149.99
£7
£21.03
£31.79
£359.10
£19.99
£60
£0.60
£168
£4.99
£20
£119
Free P&P
Free
£5
£89.99
FREE
£10.96
£1.79
```